# Orthogonal Projection onto the $ {L}_{2} $ Unit Ball

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, convex-optimization, matlab

On an article I'm reading, I find that:
if $v$ is a vector, the projection of of $v$ on the unit ball is:
$$p(v)=\frac{v}{\max\{1,\|v\|\}}$$
I know that a projection of a point $v$ into a space is the nearest point to $v$ inside the space..why the expression above?

Comment: If $v$ is outside the closed unit ball, then $\|v|| > 1$, and hence $p(v) = \tfrac{1}{\|v\|}v$, which is on the unit sphere, and hence in the closed unit ball. If, instead, $v$ is inside the closed unit ball, then $\|v\| \leq 1$, and hence $p(v) = v$. So, $p$ maps vectors outside the closed unit ball to their normalisations, which lie on the unit sphere, and does nothing to vectors that are *already* in the closed unit ball.

Comment: and it's the same of find $\arg_x \min {||x-v||} $ right?

Comment: For $x$ restricted to the closed unit ball, yes, I think so.

Comment: all clear! thank you :)

Comment: Orthogonal Projection onto the $ {\ell}_{\infty} $ / l Infinity Ball - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825747.

Comment: Orthogonal Projection onto the $ {\ell}_{1} $ / l1 Ball - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327504.

Comment: Orthogonal Projection onto the Simplex = https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402504/

Comment: @volperossa can you tell what article was it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I presume the setting is a Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$.

Then the projection onto the closed unit ball $\bar{B}$ is given by a solution to $\min_{ x \in \bar{B}} \|x-v\|$.

If $v=0$, it is clear that the solution is $x=0$, so we will assume $v \neq 0$ in the sequel.

We can write any $x \in  \mathbb{H}$ as $x = \lambda v + w$, where $w \bot v$. In particular, we have $\|x\|^2 = \lambda^2 \|v\|^2 + \|w\|^2$, and so
$\|x-v\|^2 = (1-\lambda)^2 \|v\|^2 + \|w\|^2$.
Hence if $x = \lambda v + w \in \bar{B}$, we see that $\lambda v \in \bar{B}$, and 
$\|\lambda v-v\|^2 \le \|x-v\|^2$.

If we let $V = \operatorname{sp} \{v\}$, we see that 
$\min_{ x \in \bar{B}} \|x-v\| = \min_{  \lambda v \in \bar{B}} (1-\lambda)^2 \|v\|^2 $, which is a one dimensional problem.

Since $\lambda v \in \bar{B}$ **iff** $|\lambda| \le {1 \over \|v\|}$, we see that the problem is solved by $\lambda = \min(1,{1 \over \|v\|} )$, that is, $x= \min(1,{1 \over \|v\|} )v$.

It is straightforward to see that this is the same as $p(v) $ above.

Comment: can you give a hint for a projection onto a ball around some point $c$ with radius r?
I thought maybe setting the function to be $min(||y-x-c||_2^2:||y-c||\leq r)$

Comment: @ronkurman: Show that $v$ solves the above problem **iff** $c+rv$ solves your problem. Look at the problem geometrically.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it using KKT Conditions.

Here is something I wrote once doing so (Solution to Home Work exercise I had):

[image]

I wrote MATLAB code which implements them both at [Mathematics StackExchange Question 2338491 - GitHub](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2327504).
There is a test which compares the result to a reference calculated by [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/).

Comment: can you give a hint for a projection onto a ball around some point $c$ with radius r?
I thought maybe setting the function to be $min(||y-x-c||_2^2:||y-c||\leq r)$

Comment: If you look on the code it supports any radius $ r $. Shifting is no issue. Remove the shift form the input, project and them return it to the output.

Comment: How do you conclude that $x$ is normalized and $y$ must be divided by $\|y\|_2$? Basically how from the fact that $y$ is a scaled version of $x$, you go to $\frac{y}{\|y\|_2}$?

Comment: @DontWorry, They have the same direction and you need to to do the least distance. So it must be on the envelope of the ball.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution that works in any inner product space: if $v$ is already in the unit ball, then clearly $p(v)=v$. We can thus assume that $\lVert v\rVert>1$. Given an arbitrary $a$ in the unit ball, it suffices to show that

$$\lVert v-a\rVert^2 \geq \left\lVert v-\frac v{\lVert v\rVert}\right\rVert^2.$$

Note that the RHS rewrites as $(\lVert v\rVert-1)^2$, and
expanding the squares we find the equivalent inequality:

$$\lVert v \rVert^2 - 2\langle v,a \rangle + \lVert a \rVert^2 \geq 
\lVert v\rVert^2 - 2\lVert v\rVert +1,
$$
which simplifies as
$$
\lVert a \rVert^2 - 2\langle v,a \rangle + 2\lVert v \rVert -1 \geq 
0.$$

To prove this last inequality, note that
$$\begin{align}
\lVert a \rVert^2 - 2\langle v,a \rangle + 2\lVert v \rVert -1
&\geq \lVert a \rVert^2 - 2\lVert v \rVert\lVert a \rVert + 2\lVert v \rVert -1 \tag{1}
\\ 
&= 
\lVert a \rVert^2 + 2\lVert v \rVert(1-\lVert a \rVert) -1
\\&\geq \lVert a \rVert^2 + 2(1-\lVert a \rVert) -1 \tag{2}
\\&= (\lVert a \rVert-1)^2 \geq 
0.\end{align}$$

$(1)$: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$(2)$: multiply both sides of $\lVert v \rVert \geq 1$ by the nonnegative scalar $1-\lVert a \rVert$.