# Direction of Steepest Descent within a Polyhedral Cone

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, second-order-cone-programming

Let $\mathbf c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $\mathbf c \neq \mathbf 0$ and $\mathbf A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.
What is the most efficient way to solve the following optimization problem?  Even better, does it have an analytical solution?

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\mathbf x \in \mathbb{R}^n} & &&\mathbf c^\text{T}\mathbf x \\
\text{s.t.} & && \mathbf A \mathbf x \geq \mathbf 0, \\
& && \mathbf x\geq \mathbf 0, \\
& && ||\mathbf x||_2 \leq 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I am interested in the case where $\mathbf x = \mathbf c / ||\mathbf c||$ is not a feasible solution for the problem.

Comment: How big it is? What happens if the solution is indeed what you say isn't feasible?

Comment: @Royi, I'm interested in arbitrarily large instances of the problem.  But, for concreteness, let's say $n \approx 10^6$ and $m \approx  10^6$.

Comment: If the solution is $\mathbf x = \mathbf c / ||\mathbf c||$, that's great; we're done.  But that's not the interesting case.

Comment: Could we assume the norm of $ \boldsymbol{c} $ is 1? Have you looked at my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is analytical solution.

But you can rewrite it as (Since you limited the norm any way):

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - c \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & A x \succeq \boldsymbol{0} \\
& x \succeq \boldsymbol{0} \\
& {\left\| x \right\|}_{2} \leq 1
\end{aligned}$$

The it becomes pretty close to your other question - [Projection onto a Polyhedral Cone as Minimization of Different Norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3599020) with only one more set to project upon.
I took the code I created there and added the projection onto the Euclidean ($ {L}_{2} $ Norm) ball as in [Orthogonal Projection onto the $ {L}_{2} $ Unit Ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2327432).

The MATLAB Code which is accessible in my [StackExchange Mathematics Q3599003 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q3599003).